# List index out of range error

Tags: python, bioinformatics

So I am getting  a list index out of range error in python again, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f1 = open("membrane_GO.txt","r")
new_list1 = f1.readlines()
new_list2 = new_list1
for i in range(len(new_list1)):
    if "Reactome" in new_list1[i]:
        new_list2.pop(i)
print new_list2  
f1.close()
```

I made sure that the a duplicated list is being modified as the primary list is iterated over, so that can't be the problem.

Appreciate any help
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You only duplicated a reference to the list. If you want to make a separate copy of a list, use slices: `list2 = list1[:]` or look into the `deepcopy` module.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you make a copy or not. The length of one of them will change once you pop. That means, you can't pop properly from the copy after the first pop.

Answer (score 2):

When you pop, the array size goes down. That means if the list has length 10, and you `pop(0)`, then the list has length 9. If you then `pop(9)`, which doesn't exist it will give you an out of bounds error.

Example:

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> print x, len(x)
[0,1,2,3,4], 5
>>> x.pop(0)
>>> print x, len(x)
[1,2,3,4], 4
```

This is an error in your case because you go from 0 to len(new_list1).

The approach I advise you to take is to create a new list where  "Reactome" is not in new_list1[i].

You can do this easily in a list comprehension.

```
with open("membrane_GO.txt","r") as f:
    lines = [line for line in f.readlines() if "Reactome" not in line]
print lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your list is initially ['a', 'b', 'c'],

then `list1 = list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

Then you perform iteration for `len(list2)`, ie 3 times,
Then `i` will take values 0, 1, and 2.

In each iteration you are removing one element from `list1`.

```
i = 0
remove list1[0]
new list = ['b', 'c']

i = 1
remove list1[1]
new list = ['b']

i = 2
remove list[2] which does not exist.
```

So you will get a `index out of bound error`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to TigerHawks answer:

Because you have only duplicated the reference (not the list itself), when you `pop()` an element out of `new_list2`, you also remove it from `new_list1` beceause they're both references to the same list.

Say there are 'n' elements in `new_list1` **at the start of the loop**. It will run for 'n' iterations.

Suppose then that you pop an element out of `new_list2` (and so out of `new_list1` as well), within the loop, you will get an `index out of range` error when the loop tries to access the 'nth' element of a list which now only has 'n-1' elements in it

For this to work properly use slicing to copy the list:

```
new_list2 = new_list1[:]
```

Incidentally, `for i in range(len(new_list1)):` is considered un-pythonic, I believe. A 'better' way would be to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, element in enumerate(new_list1):
    if "Reactome" in element:
        new_list2.pop(index)
```